# What's the grammatical item for "Some in tears" in this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The sentence is from a news report.

**They searched for the missing throughout the night under generator-powered flood lights as family members waited by the mounds of debris - some in tears.**

So What's the grammatical item for "Some in tears" in this sentence? A Complement?

Comment: No, not a complement, but a supplement. More specifically it's the  verbless analogue of the non-finite "some being in tears", an absolute construction.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "Family members waited by the mounds of debris - some in tears" exemplifies a phenomenon called [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping).

**Definition**: "Gapping" can be defined as a sentence with the main verb deleted but its dependents - subject, objects, adjuncts etc. - left in place. The deleted verb can be recovered from the previous sentence. The sentence will typically, but not necessarily, be introduced by a conjunction, like *and*, *or*. Linguists most commonly indicate the deleted verb with a strike-through line, so that "Mary likes beer and Sally wine" would be indicated like this:

> (1) Mary **likes** beer, and Sally <strike>likes</strike> wine.

Gapping generally requires a great deal of parallelism between the previous clause and the gapped clause, in terms of word order, grammatical functions involved, and semantics.

**Application to example**: The example in the question has a gapped clause "some in tears". It's missing verb can be understood from the previous sentence, i.e. it's *waited*. "Some" functions as the subject of this deleted verb. "In tears" is an adjunct of the verb (additional, optional information). The structure is shown below:

> (2) [<sub>subject</sub> Family members] **waited** [<sub>adjunct</sub> by the mounds of debris]. 
>   [<sub>subject</sub> Some ] <strike>waited</strike>  [<sub>adjunct</sub> in tears].

The previous clause and the gapped clause are quite parallel, as is typically the case, in that both feature a subject and an adjunct as the only elements of the verbal head and place them in the same position.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it as gapping, which occurs in coordination, but this is not a coordinative construction. I'd say it was a verbless clause functioning as a supplement.

Comment: It's true that gapped clauses occur with an initial conjunction like *and* in the majority of cases, but **not necessarily** so. There is of course also asyndetic coordination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton).

Comment: There's no coordination at all in the OP's example. An example of gapped coordination is _Sue wants to be a doctor, Max ___ a dentist_.

Comment: Isn't that similar to, *Sue waited with fortitude, Max ___ in tears.* (Also "gapped coordination" is a bad label - "a gapped clause with no conjunction" or something like that. The coordination isn't gapped.)

Comment: How would you analyze, *Family members waited by the mounds of debris - some for hours*. I don't think your analysis, as a verbless clause analogous to "being", would work, whereas my gapping analysis would work?

Answer (score 1):

> *They searched for the missing throughout the night under*
>   *generator-powered flood lights as family members waited by the mounds*
>   *of debris - some in tears.*

Syntactically it's a supplement, the verbless analogue of the non-finite clause *some being in tears* (an absolute construction).

Comment: (1) Can you link to a definition of "supplement"? It's an extremely vague term. You can use it as a non-theoretical notion, but not when it is the core of an answer. Also: a supplement of what? (2) The example has internal structure. Even you say that "they" is a subject, analogous to [they - subject  being... - predicate]. So, just saying it functions as a "supplement" without giving the internal structure of the "supplement" misses a lot. (3) Your analysis predicts you can say ?*"The missing were searched by their familiy members, some in tears." - contrary to fact. Parallelism is crucial.

Comment: A supplement is a loosely attached expression set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, **non-integrated** content. Usually an adjunct (_Luckily, we don't have to do that_), or a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause (_I saw her son, who's quite worried_).

Comment: That's informal and vague. Why is the content non-integrated? What does that even mean? Do you have a reference please?

Comment: No, it's not. Surely you know what integrated means in syntactic terms? See here for very basic info re supplements: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=pullum+on+supplements&source=bl&ots=WRGGcXbju2&sig=ACfU3U0j9cuqq8zeb-hcNS4ZExvXI5e02w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKi6WmkrThAhUFqXEKHYWeCpkQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=pullum%20on%20supplements&f=false)

Comment: No, I don't. When I hear the term, I'm thinking of a phrase that cannot be attached to another node of a syntactic tree. But then the phrase would simply be its own syntactic tree, not a "non-integrated" part of some other syntactic tree. So, no, the term does not make sense to me. (Maybe as an informal, loose notion, but not as a well-defined, formal description.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. (Note that your reference does not say "non-intergrated", but "tightly intergrated" vs. "loosely attached". Both modifiers and supplements are said to integrate into the sentence structure.)